# SELECT id WHERE

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have the Table:

```
product_id | filter_id
        68 | 2
        68 | 4
        66 | 1
        69 | 4
        67 | 1
        67 | 5
```

I want to get

```
`product_id` WHERE `filter_id` = '2' AND `filter_id` = '4'
```

ie, I need to get only `product_id` = 68

```
SELECT `product_id` FROM `filter` WHERE `filter_id` IN (2,4) - unsuitable
```

How can i do this?

Comment: what about the product_id 69 ?

Comment: Why not simply `select * from filter where product_id=68` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `group by` to select all product_ids that have both filter_id's 2 and 4

```
select product_id
from mytable
where filter_id in (2,4)
group by product_id
having count(*) = 2
```

if `(product_id, filter_id)` is not unique, then use `count(distinct filter_id) = 2` to ensure that the product has both filter_id's

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT `product_id` 
FROM `filter` 
WHERE `filter_id` IN (2,4)
GROUP BY `product_id`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `filter_id`)=2
```

Result:

```
product_id
----------
68
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4463/1)